# What's of points with condition $|z + i - 1| < 2$ in the plane?

Tags: proof-verification, complex-numbers

What's of points with condition 
$$
|z + i - 1| < 2
$$
 in the plane?

if i write $|x + i y +i -1| < 2$ this conclude

$$
(x -1)^2+(y+i)^2 < 2
$$
which is a   circle, is it true?

Comment: where  are they? @MathLover

Comment: your las equation should be $(x -1)^2+(y+1)^2 < 2$

Answer (score 2):

If you write $\vert x + iy + i - 1\vert < 2$, let's first compute the modulus, you get
$$\vert x + iy + i - 1\vert = \vert (x  - 1)+ i(y+1) \vert$$
That is
$$\vert x + iy + i - 1\vert =  \sqrt{(x  - 1)^2 + (y+1)^2}$$
So you get
$$(x  - 1)^2 + (y+1)^2 < 4$$.
Isn't this a disk of center $(1,-1)$ and radius $2$ ?

Answer (score 0):

$\mid z-z_0\mid\lt r$ is the open disc of radius $r$ centered at $z_0$.

So we have the open disc of radius $2$ centered at $1-i$.

Remember if $z=x+iy$, then $\mid z\mid=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

There are a couple errors in your calculation:  $(x-1)^2+(y+\color{red}i)^2\lt\color{red}2$.

You want: $(x-1)^2+(y+\color{blue}1)^2\lt\color{blue}{2^2}$

This is because $z-1+i=(x-1)+(y+1)i$...

Also,  if you replace $\lt$ by $=$ you get a circle.